WMI Query on __InstanceCreationEvent is invalid
Executing this query against ROOT\cimv2 namespace returns "invalid query" in WMI Explorer.  Can anyone advise why this is malformed please?
SELECT
*
FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 5
WHERE TargetInstance ISA "CIM_DataFile"
  AND TargetInstance.Drive = "C:"
  AND TargetInstance.Path="\\Users\\Default\\Documents"
  AND TargetInstance.FileName LIKE "SROPPP%"
  AND TargetInstance.Extension = "CSV"

